# How to control colors for segments of lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to create a line plot with 2 lines, and to color different segments of the lines based on a third variable. I managed to get some of this working with the simple code below, but now I'm really struggling to be able to control what colors are used (it's using 2 shades of blue that are hard to distinguish, I'm hoping to light blue and red). 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
temp <- data.frame (x=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5),y=c(5,5,4,5,4,4,5,3,3,4,3,3),z=c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,1,0), subject = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
temp$y <- factor(temp$y, levels=unique(as.character(temp$y)) )
ggplot(temp, aes(x=x, y=y, group=subject)) +
geom_line(aes(x, y, group = subject, color = z),  temp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color is essentially a scale in `ggplot` and can be controlled as such:

```
ggplot(temp, aes(x=x, y=y, group=subject)) +
geom_line(aes(x, y, group = subject, color = z),temp)  + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue","yellow")) #also accepts hex codes
```

You might have to change the code depending on what kind of scale you have, as there are different commands for color gradients, etc.

Please refer also this guide:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually

Update:

Add this and it works:

```r
temp <- temp %>% mutate(z = as.factor(z))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had tried this type of approach, but I'm getting this error: "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

Comment: @BennyD This is because ```z``` is currently a continuous variable, if you transform it to a factor it will become discrete and you can use the code I posted.